# Overview/showcase of shader techniques/uses for games

Tags: graphics, shaders, glsl, effects

I am looking for resources that can provide me with a better understanding of what kind of things shaders are used for in games, what they can do, and maybe even more importantly, what they cannot. I understand how the graphics pipeline works and all that, and I have made some very basic shaders in GLSL (mostly just to replace the fixed-function pipeline functionality), but I don't yet fully understand which things are only possible with custom shaders, which things can be done more efficiently, etc. I have been able to find some examples of certain techniques, most notably lighting, but I am looking for a more higher-level overview of their usage.

Links to and explanations of certain interesting techniques, as opposed to an overview, are also appreciated (but less than an overview ;) ), preferrably in GLSL or pseudocode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find something [here](http://www.geeks3d.com/category/geeks3d/shader-library-geeks3d/) and also [here](http://www.ozone3d.net/tutorials/). And if you want, you can find a lot of information in GPU Gems 1, 2, 3 and Shaders for Game Programming and Artists (I think, it's not about GLSL, but about HSL and shaders and games generally).

Comment: Those are some excellent resources!